# Invalid NDK - cross compile for Android using Conan manager

Tags: android, conan

I'm trying to install a Conan project for Android on a Windows host.

I created a new profile for this purpose.

Its contents:

```
[settings]
os=Android
os.api_level=23
os_build=Windows
arch_build=x86_64
arch=armv8
compiler=clang
compiler.libcxx=libc++
compiler.version=9

build_type=Release

[options]
[build_requires]
*: android-ndk/r23, cmake/3.19.0, ninja/1.10.1
[env]
```

Unfortunately, the result of invoking the command
`conan install .. --build=missing --profile android-arm64-v8a`
is an error:

```
Cross-build from 'Windows:x86_64' to 'Android:armv8'
Installing (downloading, building) binaries...
ERROR: There are invalid packages (packages that cannot exist for this configuration):
android-ndk/r23: Invalid ID: os=Android is not supported by android-ndk (no binaries are available)
android-ndk/r23: Invalid ID: os=Android is not supported by android-ndk (no binaries are available)
android-ndk/r23: Invalid ID: os=Android is not supported by android-ndk (no binaries are available)
android-ndk/r23: Invalid ID: os=Android is not supported by android-ndk (no binaries are available)
android-ndk/r23: Invalid ID: os=Android is not supported by android-ndk (no binaries are available)
android-ndk/r23: Invalid ID: os=Android is not supported by android-ndk (no binaries are available)
android-ndk/r23: Invalid ID: os=Android is not supported by android-ndk (no binaries are available)
android-ndk/r23: Invalid ID: os=Android is not supported by android-ndk (no binaries are available)
```

What am I doing wrong? How to fix it?

Comment: It seems you are still using the legacy cross-build method, while it is probable that most of the recipes in ConanCenter are prepared for the new method. Try removing ``os_build``, ``arch_build``, and use 2 profiles the ``--profile:build default`` (or ``Windows`` profile) and ``--profile:host=android``

Comment: This solution solved this problem. Thank you!

Comment: Great. Posting it as response then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are still using the legacy cross-build method.
But it is probable that most of the recipes in ConanCenter are prepared for the new cross-build method that consist of having 2 profiles:

- The "build" profile, with settings and options for the current build machine, the machine that is compiling
- The "host" profile, with settings and options for the machine that will run the code being compiled.

If you are building for Android from a Windows machine, the "build" profile will be the Windows one, and the "host" one will be the Android one

Try removing `os_build`, `arch_build` from your profile, and use 2 profiles, passing in command line both the `--profile:build default` (or Windows profile) and `--profile:host=android`